# split non-stationary vector into uneven sized chunks based on the chunk's mean R

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation

I have a vector from which I am creating a non-stationary series, and I have to divide them into chunks based on a condition. The condition is that the vector should be divided into chunks with different means. And the mean of the second chunk should be 1 standard deviation (of the second chunk) away from the mean of the first chunk. I cannot figure out how to do this. All I have right now is how to divide the vector into equal parts. Can anyone tell me the algorithm based on which I should proceed?

The data looks like this.

```
data = diffinv(rnorm(1000,0,1))
```

What I want is for it to look like this:
[image: Graph]

Comment: Please show small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: done, added the data and an image showing how it should look

Comment: 1 sd away means exactly that? or is it *at least* 1 sd away?

Comment: at least 1 sd away